# Reading from DER File Forge JS in the Browser

Tags: javascript, encryption, encoding, rsa, der

I'm trying to read binary encoded DER files (which could be password encrypted or not) in the browser using Forge.JS

https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge

I read in the file this way

```
var selectedFile = event.target.files[0];
var reader = new FileReader();

reader.onload = function(event) {
    console.log(event.target.result)
    key = event.target.result.split(',')[1];
};
```

reader.readAsDataURL(selectedFile);

I then try to read the file this way

```
var pkeyDer = forge.util.decode64(key);
var pkeyAsn1 = forge.asn1.fromDer(pkeyDer);
var privateKey = forge.pki.privateKeyFromAsn1(pkeyAsn1);
```

However, I get an error saying

> Uncaught Error: Cannot read private key. ASN.1 object does not contain an RSAPrivateKey.

Comment: are you sure the key is valid? Are you sure it's in `DER` format? Check against another bitcoin library. I recommend `bitcore`

Comment: I am sure the key is valid and it is in DER format. I'm doing anything with Bitcoin though.

Comment: What is in the file? The DER encoding of what?

Comment: DER Encoding of a Private Key